# Is there any tool to migrate RDS PostgreSQL from AWS to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, rds

I want to migrate AWS PostgreSQL to google cloud SQL. I can perform such by some basic strategy such as extract the AWS data, Create Database in GCP and Restore the extracted data in GCP. But I was wondering is there any more sophisticated way to so such as using terraform or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-postgresql-to-gcp/

For migrating MySQL there are more options available, however at the time of the writing, these only apply to MySQL:

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/migrate-data
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external